# How to Keep signalr messages even after page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am able to send signalr messages to all the clients but any time client page refreshes, the messages(li) go off the notification panel(ul).

I would want to keep the messages till a specified date.  Below is my code so far.

```
ctx.Members.Add(addThisMember);
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            notyf.Success("member successfully created.");
            await hCtx.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", $"New Member added: {addThisMember.Fullname}");
            return RedirectToAction("Members");



        public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendNotification(string Message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", Message);

        }
    }


        var connection = new signalr.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/NotificationHub").build();

    connection.on("ReceiveNotification", function (message) {
        // do whatever you want to do with `message`

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
        li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
    });

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the message in localStorage in frontend or database in backend.

**Difference between saving in frontend and backend.**

*1. If we don't need to save the data for longtime, then we can save it in localStorage. Here is the sample and test result.*

```js
"use strict";
...

window.onload = function () {
    if (connection == undefined || connection == "undefined") {
        console.log("not connect to signalr server");
        
    } else {
        if (connection._connectionState == "Connected") {
            //document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
            // load chat history messages
            for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
                var key = localStorage.key(i);
                let seconds = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(key).getTime()) / 1000;
                //Data over 15s is not loaded
                if (seconds <= 15) {
                    var value = localStorage[key];
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
                    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
                    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you
                    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
                    var msg = value;
                    li.textContent = msg;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


connection.on("Chat_ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    var msg = `${user} says ${message}`;
    li.textContent = msg;

    localStorage.setItem(new Date(), msg)
});
```

**Test Result**

[image]

*2. If we want to save the data for longtime, then we can save it in database.  You can refer the sample code to load the history messages*